# reference maven value in profile

Tags: maven-2, profile, environment

```
 <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
          <property>
            <name>environment</name>
            <value>linux-host</value>
          </property>
        </activation>
 </profile>
```

How can I reference "linux-host" inside the profile?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `${environment}`?